# Click desktop icon to execute python script in Raspbian

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

I am trying to make either a .bat or .exe file to execute a python script in linux (Raspbian). I would want to have an icon on the desktop which will be clicked (touch screen) and will then execute the python script.

The python script would need 'sudo' authorization... so if I wanted to run in terminal:

```
sudo python filelocation/name.py
```

Thanks!

Comment: your looking for a shell script I believe ... just change the permissions for it to be executable and then add the shebang to the top of the file

Comment: I looked at this 'shebang' code... could you perhaps guide me ? I read that it doesn't work when sudo is required..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `.desktop` file as nodakai already mentioned.

To have the python file executed with root permissions, either

- use something like `gksudo python program.py`. This will ask the user for the password in a normal window, no terminal involved.
- if the user shall not be asked for a password, consider an entry in the `sudoers` file, and use the usual `sudo python program.py`. (If you use this, make sure your program doesn't allow the user to do whatever they want, but only does the specific tasks you want the user to be able to do as root.)

Answer (score 4):

I've never used Raspbian myself, but I guess you can follow the standard procedure to add a custom icon to your desktop:

- http://xmodulo.com/create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-linux.html

Answer (score -1):

**name.py**

```
#!/bin/python
.....
```

then set the permissions (all the following commands are done in the terminal)

```
$ chmod a+x name.py
```

then you can run it as

```
$ ./name.py
```

if you wanted to run it as sudo you would do

```
$ sudo ./name.py
```

Comment: hmmm but I am still required to open the terminal and type... I am looking for a one-shot click and go... so click the desktop icon and this works in background, and script initiates

Comment: you should be able to click and go ... after this ... you may need to tell your OS to run as program is the default behaviour for .py files ....  you could also look into an `application.desktop` script (the easiest is to copy/paste an existing one and alter it to fit your needs)

Comment: Got it - so I would create a file (name.py) with 3 lines of code (as per above?) Click to open 'name.py' and bam - we have liftoff?

Comment: I think so ... I think rasbian by default launches .py programs as executables if applicable permission bits are set